# Aligning Marking scheme in exam solution environment

Tags: tabularx, exam, answers

Am trying to do an efficient code for writing a tabular Marking scheme inside solutions environment in exam style for this problem as an example. [image]

I did not manage to be very successful, the implementation is ad hoc using my code below.  How can I align answer marks and the last column with the exact rows and make the implementation more straightforward and efficient?

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{xstring, xcolor}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{-5pt}}p{#1}}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\pointsdroppedatright
\marksnotpoints
\marginpointname{ \points}
\pointformat{\hspace{5mm} \color{black}\big(\textbf{\themarginpoints}\big)}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Solution:}\par\noindent}
\SolutionEmphasis{\color{blue}}
\unframedsolutions

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}    % Stretch the table (vertically)
\renewcommand{\bottomrule}{\Xhline{0.5 mm}}
\renewcommand{\toprule}{\Xhline{0.3 mm}}
\renewcommand{\midrule}{\Xhline{0.3 mm}}
%\renewcommand{\cmidrule}{\Xhline{0.5 mm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[3] Some question
\droppoints
\begin{solution}
\begin{tabular}{|L{75mm}|c|L{54mm}|}
\toprule
\textbf{Marking scheme } & \textbf{marks}& comments\\ 
\midrule 
\makecell{$\begin{aligned}
\text{P(MW or WM)} = & \frac{6}{10}\times\frac{4}{9} + \frac{4}{10}\times\frac{6}{9} \\[2mm]
= & \frac{24}{90} + \frac{24}{90}\\[2mm]
= & \frac{8}{15}
\end{aligned}$} 
&\makecell{M1} 
 & \makecell[lt]{
Any one MW or WM}\\
&\makecell{M1} 
 & \makecell[lt]{
Attempt to add}\\
&\makecell{A1} 
 & \makecell[lt]{ }\\
\cmidrule{2-2}
& \LARGE{3}&\\  % total marks here

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{solution}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Probably something like `& \begin{tabular}[t]{c} M1 \\[12pt] M1 \\[12pt] A1 \end{tabular}
 &  \begin{tabular}[t]{l}Any one MW or WM \\[12pt] \\[12pt]  Attempt to add \end{tabular}
\\
\cline{2-2}
& \LARGE{3}&\\ ` is closer to the desired result? This will however still need some manual adjustments.

Comment: The following could also work: `\begin{tabular}{|Sr@{~}>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}|Sc|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\textbf{Marking scheme}} & \textbf{marks}& comments\\ 
\hline 
\text{P(MW or WM)} = & \frac{6}{10}\times\frac{4}{9} + \frac{4}{10}\times\frac{6}{9}  & M1 & Any one MW or WM \\
                   = & \frac{24}{90} + \frac{24}{90}                                  & M2 &                  \\
                   = & \frac{8}{15}                                                   & A1 & Attempt to add   \\

\cline{3-3}
& & \LARGE{3}&\\
\hline
\end{tabular}`

Comment: Needs `\usepackage{cellspace}` and `\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{10pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{10pt}`.

Comment: @Gauss did you manage to find the solution?